# how to change facebook graph api v1.0

Tags: facebook-graph-api

If you want to authenticate the application with the API you from getting to facebook graph api v2.0, you have created, please tell me how to use it as v1.0.

After authenticating as facebook graph api v1.0, Is it possible to use all the features?

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the Facebook application before April 30th (2014) you can use the entire v1 of the graph API, but after a user has authenticated under v2 it will use version 2 no matter what you configure or call (if it was productive and set to v1)

An example to use version 1 on the FB SDK for Javascript:

```
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'your-fb-app-id',
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      version: "v1.0", // here is the version (not really necessary for v1)
      frictionlessRequests : false
    });
```